# iOS : How a make a text display for a certain duration only during startup program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I want to put a text label during the start up of a program, some sort of a text instruction for 5 second only and disappear. May I know how to do so in iOS ? Here is my code example.

```
NSString *displayText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Please select your item.",

startup.text = displayText ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the following statement,

```
startup.text = displayText ;
```

start a `NSTimer` that will fire after certain duration.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

In `hideLabel:` method, you hide that.

Comment: OK thanks for the guide, i will do this homework to see how far i can go.